# Show Pagenumbers using mat-paginator angular 5 material

Tags: angular, angular5

How to show page numbers using mat-paginator in angular 5. Currently it's supporting only arrows but i want to show page numbers like ngx-paginator

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are asking specifically about how to display the numbers of the items visible on the page. I believe that when I began using the below directives, the item(s) range appeared automatically. However, if you're referring to the page size options or the number of items visible on the page, the following code will help you.

You need to use directives to show the page numbers and page size options. Here is an example of paginator code for your template that shows what you're looking for:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
           [pageSize]="10"
           [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
            [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
</mat-paginator>
```

You can use `@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;` to modify the paginator from code.

Additionally, here two links to the relevant parts of the Angular Material documentation to help you out:

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview
https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Comment: no it won't work as I tried earlier itself. I fixed by using ngx-paginator with mat-table.